# How can i make 3 independently scrollable columns

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website on which I want to have 3 independently scrollable `<div>` elements.

The html code is this:

```
<div class="sidebar">Content</div>
<div id="window">Some very long content</div>
<div class="sidebar">More content</div>
```

The associated css is this:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#window {
    font-family: monospace;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

From what I saw via searching the internet, this is supposed to work. But I don't see any scrollbars at all.

Why?

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: `overflow: auto` only adds scrollbars if necessary. Is your content long enough to trigger them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height: 100%` as a percentage only affects the height of the element if that element's parent has an explicit height. The height of the `body` tag by default is the height of the content, not the full height of the window.

Try adding this:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to not have any effect

Comment: I just realized i had another sourrounding div which did not have the `heigth: 100%;` attribute. Adding it fixed the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Because of your height: 100%; your divs will just adjust to the height of the text. By changing your height to for example: 250px your code will work.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The problem is that i want it to span full screen heigth. I cannot predict how high the window is